# Simple command like redis BITFIELD GET in SLOWLOG with runtime at 1500 to 2000 microseconds

Tags: performance, redis, bit-fields

the host CPU usage is normal like usual, but could not get why a simple bitfield operation which reads the initial 32 bits in a string, takes so much time, when Redis is single threaded and Slowlog only measures the execution time, when the thread is busy.
This BITFIELD get operation is part of a Lua script, but that should not affect the slowlog computation.
Please let me know, what to look into, to know the cause of this slowness.

Comment: Can you add the details for reproducing this?

Comment: @ItamarHaber I observed this in production, and wanted to investigate why a simple operation was taking so much time. I checked the host CPU and RAM usage during that period, and there was nothing unusual about it. 
Just wondering, what else might have caused Redis to slow down, during the command execution.

Comment: Can it be a latency issue?

Comment: @gliatsos this BITFIELD GET operation reads the first 32 bits in the payload, which is a very simple operation.

Comment: Which Redis version do you have? Is this constantly reproducible? Or appeared just once?

Comment: @gliatsos Redis 3.2.10 . It occurred for 2 days in production, and later after a while, it occurred again

Comment: @gliatsos It happened 215 times in production out of 1 crore BITFIELD operations in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @sumanth232 Could you please check the execution time without being inside the Lua script that you mention?

Comment: @gliatsos being in a lua script does not matter here, as SLOWLOG computation is solely between the command start and finish